Thermodynamics, cooling curves
It is well known that temperature is a measure of the average kinetic energy of the medium particles. In the heating curve, when heat is added the average kinetic energy increases and the temperature of the system increases accordingly, except at phase change plateau region. Water for example at its melting point plateau, when heat is added water molecules use it to weaken the bonds of the solid ice and then tranforms to liquid water with a weaker hydrogen bonds. The average kinetic energy remains the same, which explains why temperature remains the same as well.
The same discussion holds true for the boiling point plateau, except for the fact that the hydrogen bond is completely broken, and liquid water becomes vapor.
My problem is with the cooling curve. I understand that when heat is removed, the average kinetic energy decreases and the temperature of the system decreases accordingly. But the problem is I can't get my head around what is going on in the plateau region when water for example is cooling down?
For example, at the freezing point plateau, water molecules become more tied in the crystal structure of ice, loosing some of its kinetic energy, why temperature doesn't drop accordingly and remains 0 degree celsius at this point?
What makes temperature constant at the plateau region in the cooling curves in general?

Reverse your melting argument - why would heating do one thing and cooling not undo it?

@JonCuster thank you for replying!  I just want to know how cooling undo it, what is the mechanism?

How did heating ‘do it’? Why doesn’t cooling, well, undo it?

@JonCuster cooling does it, okay. But how, the mechanism, from a molecular standpoint?

The reverse of the mechanism for melting.

Remember on cooling you are pulling heat out, its just the temperature does not change until it is all solid


For example, at the freezing point plateau, water molecules become
more tied in the crystal structure of ice, loosing some of its kinetic
energy, why temperature doesn't drop accordingly and remains 0 degree
celsius at this point?

Even though during heat extraction the molecular motion in ice is constrained to be primarily vibrational, the average molecular kinetic energy of the solid in the liquid-solid mixture is the same as the average molecular kinetic energy of the liquid phase, so that they are at the same temperature.
I’ve emphasized average because a greater percentage of the total internal molecular energy of the liquid phase is molecular potential energy, due to greater molecular separation, whereas the opposite is the case for the solid phase.
So while the total kinetic energy of the solid phase decreases, a greater percentage of its total internal molecular energy is kinetic than it is in the liquid phase.
One reason it may be difficult to get one’s head around the above is we are used to thinking about temperature only in terms of the average translational kinetic energy, ignoring the potential direct or indirect contributions of molecular vibrational and rotational modes. For a discussion on this see “What is temperature” on the Hyperphysics website.
Hope this helps.
